# PDF File Import R

Tags: r, pdf, text, import

I have multiple **.pdf-files** (stored in a local folder), that contain text. I would like to import the .pdf-files (i.e., the texts) in R. I applied the function '`read_dir`' (R package: `[textreadr][1]`)

```
library ("textreadr")
Data <- read_dir("<MY PATH>")
```

The function works well. BUT. For several files, that include **special characters** (i.e., letters) in their **names** (such as '`ć`'; e.g., 'filenameć.pdf'), the function did **not work** (error message: '`The following files failed to read in and were removed:`' …).

What can I do?

I tried to **rename the files** via R (**did not work** (probably due to the same reasons)). That might be a workaround.

I did not want to rename the files manually :)

**Follow-Up (only for experts):**
For several files, I got one of the following error messages (and I have no idea why):

```
PDF error: Mismatch between font type and embedded font file
```

or

```
PDF error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
```

Any suggestions or hints how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Likely the issue concerns the encoding of the file names. If you absolutely want to use R to rename the files for you, the function you want to use is iconv, determine the encoding of the file names and then convert them to utf-8.

However, a much better system would imply renaming them using bash from command line. Can you provide a more complete set of examples?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).